# Adjust border-radius on input type search not working on mobile safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

Here's my html:

```
    <form action="/" method="get" class="searchForm">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Search...">
        <input type="submit" value="">
    </form>
```

and my css:

```
    input[type="search"]{
        height: 31px;
        width: 254px;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-right: none;
        padding: 0 5px;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
    }
```

It works fine in all browsers except mobile safari where it gives each corner an equal radius. If I change the input type to text it works, but for search and submit it doesn't.

I've tried adding:

```
    input {
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        border-radius: 0 !important;
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

1. using -webkit prefix for border radius.
2. long hand version of using border radius (see this :- http://blog.lesjames.com/post/8510513712/mobile-safari-and-border-radius)

if this doesn't work try to provide more details like ios version, ipad/iphone.
i tested on iphone with ios 5.1 and 4.3, worked perfect for me if using -webkit-appearance:none;

Comment: I tried these and still no luck. I'm using ios 5.1.1. Here's a [link](http://www.keithcarter.graphitedesign.com/) Thanks!

Comment: your link don't work on mine also, but when i change -webkit-appearance from textfield(as you have written in your site) to none, it work for me. 
Like in http://jsfiddle.net/Eg9rP/3/ , the first one is not showing correctly while second one is showing correctly.